# Firebase db not syncing in Huawei CAM-L21

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, huawei-mobile-services

I am developing an app using Firebase Mobile Database. To enable offline capabilities I have used:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

And:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("somechildtable").keepSynced(true);
```

Everything is working as expected in other devices except **Huawei Cam-L21**. When user at first login/signup it works fine but after sometime it stop syncing. I have tried adding my app in the list of protected apps but no use.

I there anybody who can tell me what actually I am wrong at?